# How redirect cancel function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm not a programmer. I don't want to protect with a strong secure code my page. I just need one option I'm missing in my code and can't figure out how to add it.

```
<script language="Javascript">
<!--

var password = "lala"

var x = prompt("","")

if (x.toLowerCase() == password) {
location = "http://google.com";
}

else {
alert("Fail")
location = "http://facebook.com"
}

//-->
</script>
```

As you can see it's so dump but I need it. When I press Cancel button instead of writing true or false text, website still opens. I want to include in this script cancel button function (control it, you know) whitch would redirect to another website if press on it (as it is with true or false functions). I don't want to creat a special button or an input for it.

Update: I would like to include this script in a page which i am redirecting to. Could anyone tell me:
 1. How can i modify this script to make it work only once? 
 2. Is it anything to do with browser's cookies?

p.s. Done :)

Comment: Java ≠ Javascript.  Retagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user presses cancel, prompt will return null. So do like this:

```
if(x == null) // Cancel
{
    alert('Cancel');
}
else if (x.toLowerCase() == password) { // Correct password
    location = "http://google.com";
}
else { // Wrong password
    alert("Fail")
    location = "http://facebook.com"
}
```

However, I'm not sure if all browsers will return null when the user presses cancel. (I have tested in Opera)

Comment: Thnx a lot, looks like it's working in other browsers either. But i want to include this script in a page which i am redirecting to. 
1. How can i modify this script to make it work only once?
2. Is it anything to do with browser's cookies?

Comment: @Argentum You could use cookies, search for document.cookie, or maybe add something in the query string (the part of an url after "?"). Both of these solutions feel a bit broken, but I guess they are okey for the simple hack you are doing. (I hope you realize that anyone can find the password by right-clicking in their browser and looking at the source.)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var x = prompt("","");

if( x == null || x == '')
    return;

if (x.toLowerCase() == password) {
    location = "http://google.com";
}

else {
    alert("Fail")
    location = "http://facebook.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect your browser to a URL use following snippet in your Javascript:

```
top.location.href = "http://google.com";
```